# How to identify PIDs which are writing to SWAP memory in Linux

Tags: linux, memory, virtual-memory

Server is using swap memory when there is enough RAM is available because of which users are facing intermittent slowness and performance issues.
In the free command I can see that there is 6927mbs of swap is used but when I sorted the PIDs through top i found only 2 pids that to consuming few kbs.

Details:-

```
free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:        129043     123398       5644      56782        147      59134
-/+ buffers/cache:      64116      64926
Swap:         8191       6927       1264
```

top output sorted by SWAP usage:-

```
top - 11:08:18 up 17 days,  8:29, 318 users,  load average: 18.64, 18.34, 17.73
Tasks: 3115 total,  12 running, 3103 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 26.3%us,  3.5%sy,  0.0%ni, 67.5%id,  2.5%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.1%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  132140360k total, 131050280k used,  1090080k free,    27072k buffers
Swap:  8388604k total,  7093580k used,  1295024k free, 60220780k cached

   PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  **SWAP** COMMAND
  2353 mfg       20   0 38.6g 532m 2452 S  0.2  0.4   9:06.68 **4096** java
 23499 mfg       20   0 24.4g 358m 245m S  0.0  0.3   0:56.71 **2692** D_finqonddb_AS_
     1 root      20   0 23600  724  368 S  0.0  0.0   7:20.05    0 init
     2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   3:08.08    0 kthreadd
     3 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   1:04.47    0 migration/0
```

swappiness value

```
cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
**1**
```

Please help me on how to identify which processes are using/writing to the SWAP memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

smaps file stores swap details. Used below script to get swap consuming PIDs details.

```
ps ax -o pid,args | grep -v '^  PID'|sed -e 's,^ *,,' > /tmp/ps_ax.output
echo -n >/tmp/results
for swappid in $(grep -l Swap /proc/[1-9]*/smaps ); do
        swapusage=0
        for x in $( grep Swap $swappid 2>/dev/null |grep -v '\W0 kB'|awk '{print $2}' ); do
                let swapusage+=$x
        done
        pid=$(echo $swappid| cut -d' ' -f3|cut -d'/' -f3)
        if ( [ $swapusage -ne 0 ] ); then
                echo -ne "$swapusage kb\t\t" >>/tmp/results
                egrep "^$pid " /tmp/ps_ax.output |sed -e 's,^[0-9]* ,,' >>/tmp/results
        fi
done
echo "top swap using processes which are still running:"
sort -nr /tmp/results | head -n 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look using smem or check /proc/-PID-/status for the line starting with VmSwap.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamkb/how-to-review-swap-space-usage-on-a-linux-server-865042927.html has this nice CLI expression to report that line and the process name for all PIDs:

for file in /proc/*/status ; do awk '/VmSwap|Name/{printf $2 " " $3}END{ print ""}' $file; done | sort -k 2 -n -r | less

Comment: I used your command to find the processes that using SWAP. Swap usage from your command and the free command swap usages does not add up. see below

`$ for file in /proc/*/status ; do awk '/VmSwap|Name/{printf $2 " " $3}END{ print ""}' $file; done | sort -k 2 -n -r |awk '{ sum+=$2} END {print sum }'
658852`
`$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         40172      26122      14050       9993        377      13316
-/+ buffers/cache:      12428      27744
Swap:         8191       **5292**       2899`

Can anyone explain this behaviour?